# Cant' load custom css for Swagger ASP.Net Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am trying to load a custom .css for my swagger page that I added to an ASP.Net Core 6 Web API application.

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.Logger.LogInformation("Setup application");
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.None);
        c.InjectStylesheet("/swagger-ui/custom.css");
    });

}

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
    ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Logger.LogInformation("Running application");
app.Run();
```

I added 'swagger-ui' folder in my project folder and added 'custom.css' file in the folder. Its build action is set to 'Embedded resource' and copied to output folder. I have added the inject to my UseSwaggerUI in Program.cs, but when the swagger page loads it still loads the default 'swaggerui.css' sheet. What am I missing?

Comment: you don't need to make it `Embedded resource`. and you should create swagger-ui folder inside wwwroot folder.

Comment: @CodingMytra I don't have a wwwroot folder. Not sure if thats because I am on .net Core6. But I fixed my issue by specifying a FileProvider and RequestPath in the StaticFileOptions

Answer (score 2):

I found that specifying the static file path in the staticFile options solved it for me.

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "swagger-ui")),
    RequestPath = "/swagger-ui"
});
```